# iterrows to compare values and add a new column

Tags: python, pandas, set, boolean

I have a dataframe with one (column `B`) of the columns containing a list of value. For each row, I want to compare the value in this list column with a `reference` list.  If the value in `B` contains the same value in the `reference`, I want to return `Yes` to a third column (column `result`); if the value in `B` contains different values in `reference`, I want to return `No`. Moreover, the items in the column list are not ordered.

The input df is here, the dtype of `B` is an object.

```
B 
1st, 2nd, 3rd
2nd, 4th, 5th
2nd, 1st, 3rd
4th, 5th, 6th
```

Compare with the reference list `[1st,  2nd, 3rd]`. the expected output

```
B                      Results
1st, 2nd, 3rd          Yes
2nd, 4th, 5th          No
2nd, 1st, 3rd          Yes
4th, 5th, 6th          No
```

I tried the code below, but they didn't add a new column for me:

```
for index, row in df[['B']].iterrows():
    if set(row['B']) == set(['1st', '2nd', '3rd']):    
        row['Results'] = "Yes"
    else:
        row['Results'] = "No"
```

Or is there any easier way to achieve this? E.g., not looping by rows?

Comment: "Or is there any easier way to achieve this? E.g., not looping by rows?" *In general*, the way in Pandas that you "make a column where each value depends on other values in the row" is that you first figure out the code that makes that value given a row, and then you *use Pandas tools* to do the looping. Similarly with Numpy and "broadcasting" operations. So, yes, you should *expect* an easier way whenever the question looks like this. That's why these libraries are as popular as they are.

Comment: As an aside: `set(['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])` is more neatly written `{'1st', '2nd', '3rd'}`.

Comment: BTW: the official documentation [includes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html) a lot of tutorial links, to help you get used to the Pandas way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Since each row in "B" is a list but you want to compare it with a set, you'll inevitably have to iterate over rows to at least convert each list to a set imo.

One options is to convert each list in "B" to a set and then compare with `ref_set` directly to get a boolean Series. Finally use `np.where` to assign "yes", "no" values.

```
ref_set = set(['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])
df['results'] = np.where(df['B'].apply(set) == ref_set, 'yes', 'no')
```

another options is to use a list comprehension:

```
df['results'] = ['yes' if set(x)==ref_set else 'no' for x in df['B']]
```

Output:

```
                 B results
0  [1st, 2nd, 3rd]     yes
1  [2nd, 4th, 5th]      no
2  [2nd, 1st, 3rd]     yes
3  [4th, 5th, 6th]      no
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
base = set(['1st','2nd','3rd'])
row['results'] = row['B'].apply( lambda k: 'Yes' if set(k) == base else 'No' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Results']=df['B'].str.split(',').map(set).apply(lambda x: len(x.difference(lst))).eq(0)
```

Or if you must denote by Yes, No

```
df['Results']=np.where(df['B'].str.split(',').map(set).apply(lambda x: len(x.difference(lst))).eq(0),'Yes','No')
```